# Why do i get syntax error at end problem with pattern matching

Tags: ocaml

I have to make a function that takes list a list and returns list of pairs of first and last element,2nd and 2nd last and so forth It doesn't matter if the list has  even or odd number of elements because if its odd i will just ignore the middle element.The idea i have is that make a new rec fun that takes old list and its revers as input i think i finished the code but i get Syntax error for ;;

```
let lip l =
    if [] then [] 
    else let l1=l l2=List.rev l in 
         let rec lp l1 l2 = match l1,l2 with 
        | [],[] ->[]
        | [],h2::t2->[]
        | h1::_,h2::_ -> 
        if (List.length l -2) >= 0 then [(h1,h2)]@ lp(List.tl l1) t2
        else [] ;;
```

Comment: One issue is definitely the `if []` -- either write `if l = []` or `match l with | [] -> [] | otherpattern -> somelist`

Comment: Also multiple bindings as in `let l1=l l2=List.rev l in` don't work -- ` let l1=l in let l2=List.rev l in`. Not sure why you introduce `l1` as an alias for `l` at all. Also `t2` is an unknown variable -- should it be an additional argument or is it a typo?

Comment: `t2` is bound by the pattern match. It's not an undefined variable.

Comment: Ah right, just saw it... it's just missing in that branch.

Comment: Whoops--good point!

Comment: Just a tip (mostly because it annoys me to no end and has occurred in several of your questions): `[(h1, h2)] @ lp(...)` is equivalent to `(h1, h2) :: lp(...)`, but much less convoluted and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few errors in your code.

I think the specific error you're seeing is caused by the fact that there is no `in` after `let rec lp ...`.

Every `let` that's not at the top level of a module needs to be followed by `in`. One way to think of it is that it's a way of declaring a local variable for use in the expression that appears after `in`. But you need to have the `in expr`.

Another way to look at it is that you're defining a function named `lp` but you're not calling it anywhere.

As @lambda.xy.x points out, you can't say `if [] then ...` because `[]` isn't of type `bool`. And you can't say `let x = e1 y = e2 in ...`. The correct form for this is `let x = e1 in let y = e2 in ...`

(Or you can write `let x, y = e1, e2 in ...`, which looks nicer for defining two similar variables to two similar values.)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should at least compile:

```
let lip list1 =
  if list1 = [] then []
  else
    let list2=List.rev list1 in 
    let rec lp l1 l2 = match l1,l2 with 
      | [], [] ->[]
      | [], _::_->[]
      | h1::_::_, h2::t2 -> (* l1 length >= 2*)
        (h1,h2) :: lp(List.tl l1) t2
      | h1::_,h2::t2 ->     (* l1 length = 1 *)
        []
    in
    []
```

I have made the following changes:

- renamed the arguments of `lip` to make clear they are different from the arguments of `lp`
- removed the alias `let l1 = l`
- changed the if condition to a term of type boolean -- there's not much to compare, so I assume you are checking list1
- replaced the list length condition by a pattern match against two heads
- the else path is the second match - it might be better to rewrite that one to `| [h1, _] -> ...`
- the definition of `lp` needs to be followed with the actual body of `lip` - to make it compile, we just return `[]` at the moment but you probably would like something else there

As @Jeffrey Scofield already mentioned, you are not using `lp` in your code. It could help if you added a comment that explains what you'd like to achieve and what the intended role of `lp` is.